# Python: compare and sort tuples in list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, networkx

I'm trying to sort a list of points (their IDs). The tuples are a result of a minimum spanning tree (using networkx) of a graph in which every node is connected to every other node, but their weights differ. I need to extract a (shortest) path for each tree that will give me the right order of the edges. But the result of the tuples of the MST is unordered, and if I use it as it is, I get bad results, so I need to sort the tupes. I have some example lists of tuples:

```
L1: [(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 3)]
L2: [(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
L3: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

L1 and L2 are not sorted as I want, L3 is. As you might notice, I need the order of the list to be succeeding points/tuples, to derive the order of the tree. L1 and L2 need to be sorted like:

```
L1: [(1, 0), (0, 3), (3, 2)] : order = 1-0-3-2
L2: [(0, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)] : order = 0-3-2-1

# some way to do this in pseudo code would be
for tuple in list:
    # compare current tuple with previous and next (if exist)
    if tuple[1] != next[0]:
        reverse tuple
    if tuple[0] != prev[1]:
        reverse tuple
    etc...
```

I have tried to sort the list by defining multiple if/elif statements (see above), but that gets messy and chaotic. I've seen sorting with things like `sorted(L1, key=customsort)`, but I couldn't find ways to compare multiple tuples, I hope something like that is possible!

Comment: are the list guaranteed to be MST sorted? as in sorted by first index first and by second index after? Also MST does not necessarily out put a path. What about `[(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)]` - that's a valid MST for 4 nodes, but not a path - so are the lists guaranteed to symbolize a path - specifically each index appears at most twice, and only 2 appear once?

Comment: True, but in my case the MST is a way to find the correct order for points that make up a line. So a set of points (a,b,c,d) are used to make a graph, with the distance between two points as weight for an edge between 2 points. And since the points are always linear, the resulting MST is a linear path. But in essence you are definitely right.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to find the start of the path, which according to the comments is one of two indices appearing once, while building a method to traverse continuously. Assuming `n` nodes we can build something to help us (this solution I think is the clear, and linear, but maybe not best/most elegant):

```
path = [[] for _ in range(n)]
stops= [2 for _ in range(n)]
for edge in result:
    for i in range(2):
        path[edge[i]].append(edge[1-i])
        stops[edge[i]] -= 1
for current in range(len(stops)):
    if stops[current]: break
```

`path` here saves in each index (which is a node) the two/one other node/s it connects to. the inner loop looks at the points in the edge - `edge[0],edge[1]`. The `1-i` just flips a 1 with 0.

`stops` counts how many times a node appeared. Each node appears twice in a path, except two - these will be the only places in the array which aren't 0. This isn't a must, just an easy place to start.

`current` looks for such a non-zero entry to start from.

Now rebuild by traversing a path to create a proper list of tuples like you needed:

```
result = [(current,path[current][0])] #Only one option!
current= path[current][0]
while stops[current]:
   next = path[current][1] if path[current][0] == current else path[current][0]
   result.append((current,next))
   current = next
```

Notice I didn't use some of the knowns in the original list, such as the order. You can use that to improve this.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I have a hard time understanding what it does.. What exactly are you building and rebuilding and why?

Comment: I fleshed out the answer to explain. The `path` is just an array where each index represents a node, and holds a list of what it connects to - I rebuild the result to be a list of tuples like you required.

Comment: and what does `next = path[current][0] == current ? path[current][1] : path[current][0]` do? I'm not familiar with the usage of `?` in Python? Or is it meant to be a real question to me? And what does the `:` mean?

Comment: Ahh, the trinary operator burrowed from `C`. It's good python, and it does as it reads: condition is true ? take this : otherwise this. You can assign this as well as you see. It's a short if-else construct. In the context I'm taking the node from the following two possible nodes which isn't myself - I don't want to go forward and back.

Comment: @Matthie456 While programming today I noted a foul and gross mistake by me. The trinary operator does not exist in python in the C form, but in the perl form (if else one liner). I fixed it. I'm really really sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try refining the above answer, and making the individual operations simpler.

```
import collections


def sort_mst(lst):
    unordered = [frozenset(elem) for elem in lst]
    elems = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for elem in unordered:
        # Assumption: elem has length 2
        for index in elem:
            # Assumption: each set will have an elem added no more than twice.
            elems[index].add(elem)
    # For theoretically faster, but non-deterministic behavior, use next()
    # instead of min()
    index = min(k for k, v in elems.items() if len(v) == 1)
    results = []
    while elems[index]:
        connection, = elems[index]
        next_index, = connection - {index}
        results.append((index, next_index))
        index = next_index
        elems[index] -= {connection}
    return results
```

This uses sets to discard unneeded ordering information. It first converts all tuples to sets, then creates a reverse mapping from indices to the sets that contain them.

Next, it finds an index only associated with one set, and uses that to traverse the reverse mapping, discarding sets from it as it adds them to the output list. When there's no set associated with an index, after it discards the preceding set, then it knows it reached the other end, and is done.